# What is the name of this battery contact type?

Tags: batteries, contact

In the following video (timestamped): https://youtu.be/rylbFnTgFI8?t=107, you can very briefly see a C shaped battery contact within the "cap" of the battery kit.

[image: Contacts]

The benefit of this specific contact is that, it is both spring-y and allows connection via screwing.

However, I have been completely unable to find its name, both in battery contact guides and in sales websites. Does anybody know its name, or if it is even sold anywhere? If not, any alternatives that may be similar?

Comment: I would guess that it's a proprietary part, seeing as it's designed to go into a molded plastic holder.  Also, please do not emulate the method shown of "attaching" the sense leads.

Comment: @vir That doesn't seem to be a good criteria for claiming it's proprietary, considering all battery contacts are made to be attached in some very specific way -but I was hoping that wouldn't be the answer. And yes, I was not planning on squeezing the BMS balancing cables under the strips. Still, are there no contacts that serve this same purpose?

Comment: please add more views to your post

Comment: @jsotola Unfortunately, I cannot. This is the only footage I know of this contact. It is a C shape, with the "top" of the C making contact with the battery, and the "bottom" of the C having a hole and screwed to the other side.

Comment: I have worked on the design of around half a dozen different battery powered toys. We did custom battery terminals and custom plastic for every single one. So I tend to agree with vir. The barrier for an established manufacturer to design a new battery contact is very low. The tooling for the supplier is not too expensive or difficult to set up. So there is no incentive to try to make any pre-existing contact work unless it is a PERFECT fit.

Comment: Keystone Electronics (keyelco.com) has a lot of battery contacts. Are any of them what you are looking for? https://www.keyelco.com/category.cfm/Battery-Coin-Cell-Holders-Contacts-Clips/Cylindrical-Cell-Contacts/p/404/id/410

Comment: https://www.keyelco.com/category.cfm/Cylindrical-Cell-Contacts/17-19-mm-Dia-Cell-Contacts/p/404/id/410/c_id/843

Comment: @mkeith Do you know if there are services aimed at consumers/hobbyists to design such metal parts? Battery contacts, of course, but perhaps also washers, screws... of differing materials (copper, nickel, steel...). If yes, any recommendations on how to find them / design for them without failing miserably?

Comment: @ZeroZ30o I do not know of any such thing. If you can make a drawing of what you want, you can request quotes from suppliers. But I would not expect anything to be cheap enough. For small quantity parts what you want to do is focus on production techniques that do not use tooling. So laser sheet metal or foil, CNC, etc. Getting stuff made in China is relatively cheap. But you need to specify what you want. Design advice and assistance is not provided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The contact is proprietary to the Vruzend system, designed to work with the holder to make a secure, low-resistance contact with the battery.

So this C-shaped contact is their special-sauce that, together with the screw posts and holder, provides an alternative to spot-welding contacts onto the batteries.

Answer (score 4):

It is called a `leaf spring contact`.

That exact one is sold at https://vruzend.com

Comment: They don’t sell the contacts. They sell the holders with contacts.